# Switching hot between host operating system and guest operating system

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, macos-sierra

I am researching for hours but I could not find. I am using windows 10 as main operating system. In order to build mobile app I installed sierra on latest vmware pro workstation. I am using sierra exlusive mode. I want to taking control via a shortcut key or touchpad between two operating systems. So, when I press button, it will pass guest operating system and when I press again, it will pass main operating system. How can I do that? Is there any program or vmware tool? And can you suggest more beneficial way to use xcode instead of vmware?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to taking control via a shortcut key or touchpad between two operating systems. So, when I press button, it will pass guest operating system and when I press again, it will pass main operating system.

VMware Workstation/Player 10 and later bundle [`vmware-kvm`, which does exactly that](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/03/whats-cool-vmware-kvm-utility.html).