# Increasing video card memory on macOS virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, xcode, macos-sierra

I am researching for hours but I could not find. I am using Windows 10 as main operating system. In order to build mobile app, I installed sierra on latest VMware 12 pro workstation. I have done it VMware KVM. I want to increase performance of Sierra.

I have done Beamoff and installed Darwin tools. It's perforfamnce boosted a bit. Now video card on guest machine seems 128 MB.

How can I increase video card memory. Laptop is including 2 gb NVIDIA 540m. I do not use guest machine as 128 MB.How can I do that? Is there any program or vmware tool?

And can you suggest more beneficial way to using xCode instead of VMware?

Comment: [Maybe that's helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587083/virtualbox-how-to-increase-video-memory) Virtual Box video Memory can be increased up to 256 MB

Comment: Since you seem to be the same person as the one who asked [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1235809/switching-hot-between-host-operating-system-and-guest-operating-system), I suggest that you ask more general  questions stop talking about macOS Sierra in your questions.  [Questions about virtualizing macOS on non-Apple hardware are considered off-topic](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2792/how-should-we-act-upon-install-os-x-as-virtual-machine-questions).

Comment: Also, upvoting or accepting helpful answers would encourage people to answer any future questions.

Comment: Sorry. We don’t support Hackintoshes which is what running macOS on  Windows 10 is.

Answer (score 0):

Run VMware Workstation, open the VM, and choose VM > Settings > Hardware > Display.  Make sure that the "Accelerate 3D graphics" checkbox is ticked, and then there should be a "Graphics memory" ComboBox that allows you to increase the amount.

Comment: I did what you said and increased to 512 MB. But when I run sierra , it seems again 128 MB

Comment: @BurakNurçiçek I can't help you with that part.  Running macOS inside of VMware Workstation is not supported.